# Is ReportViewer capable of Mailing Labels?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, mailing-list

I’m using C# with VS2008 Standard. Is it possible for ReportViewer to create mailing labels? Or is it not really meant for that?

PS.I don't want to use MS Word in any way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very possible.  You just have to make sure the heights and widths of your grid cells are appropriate for the type of label you want to print.

Comment: Just some clarification, do I need to use Word? Or can it all be done in ReportViewer?

Comment: Sorry, if that wasn't clear.  I was simply saying this was built in to Word, but not ReportViewer.  So, no, you don't need to use word.

Comment: Thank you Craig, I'll look into into more deeply then. Appreciate your time.